# Why do pythonics prefer pip over their OS's package managers?

Tags: python, pip, package-managers

When reading tutorials and readmes I often see people advertising to install python packages with `pip`, even when they are using an operating system, which has a nice package manager like `apt`. Yet in real life I only met people who would only install things with their OS's package manager, reasoning that this package manager will treat all packages the same, no matter if python or not.

Comment: By the way, the most common term is [_"Pythonista"_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythonista#Name_and_neologisms). :)

Comment: Thanks Pedro, didn't know that before!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two main reasons that Pythonistas generally recommend `pip`. The first is that it is the one package manager that is pretty much guaranteed to come with a Python installation, and therefore, independent of the OS on which you are using it. This makes it easier to provide instructions that work on Windows and OS X, as well as your favourite Linux.

Perhaps more importantly, `pip` works very nicely with `virtualenv`, which allows you to easily have multiple conflicting package configurations and test them without breaking the global Python installation. If I remember correctly, this is because `pip` is itself a Python program and it automatically runs within the current `virtualenv` sandbox. OS-level package managers obviously do not do this, since it isn't their job.

Also, as @Henry points out below, it's easier to just list your package in a single place (PyPI) rather than depending on the Debian/Ubuntu/Fedora maintainers to include it in their package list. Less popular packages will almost never make it into a distribution's package list.

That said, I often find that installing global libraries (`numpy`, for example) is easier and less painful with `apt-get` or your favourite alternative.

Comment: It also allows a package developer to produce an installable, without requiring it be taken up by a distribution. `pip install` is much easier than doing the build manually.

Comment: and actually, I think that package management systems shall just become a frontend to pip, so they can bring requirements that are outside the scope of pip. And that could also apply to gems, cpan, ctan etc.. But that's a long running troll and nobody want to move on that topic.